# Error when trying to add ReactiveForms to a component `Can't bind to 'formGroup'...`

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to angular/ionic, got a problem when trying to use `ReactiveFormsModule` on ionic angular component, getting error:

`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`

When I add `ReactiveFormsModule` to a `somepage.page.ts` it does work, as I can include it `somepage.module.ts`, however when I want to add it on a component view, importing necessary modules from app.module.ts, it doesn't work.

> app.module.ts

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

> someview.component.ts

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export class SomeviewComponent implements OnInit {
  newCaseFormGroup: FormGroup;
  name: AbstractControl;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.newCaseFormGroup = formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.name = this.newCaseFormGroup.controls['name'];
  }
}
```

> someview.component.html

```js
  <form [formGroup]="newCaseFormGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
    <input type="submit" [disabled]="!newCaseFormGroup.valid">
  </form>
```

`someview.component.html` is loaded in `somepage.page.ts` via shared module:

> shared-module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SomeviewComponent } from '../components/someview/someview.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SomeviewComponent
    ],
    providers: [],
    exports: [
        SomeviewComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

My understanding was that if I include modules in `app.module.ts` they should be available throughout the app.

I have tried also adding them to `somepage.page.ts` which loads this component someview.component.ts, results are the same.

Once again, when I add reactive forms to a somepage.page.ts and include modules from somepage.module.ts it works as expected. I am missing some little thing to make it work on component.

Thanks again in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have other modules then `app.module.ts` ? Becous if you have lazy loaded modules you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` to them to.

Comment: Are the `someview.component.ts` is declared in same module you import `FormModules` ?

Comment: Hm, look at original post I just updated how component is loaded. It's loaded via shared module (because other pages reuse that component).

I supposed I need to import reactive form in a shared module no? That might be a next thing to try.

Comment: import shared module inside app module

Comment: Components kep in your `app.module.ts` or in some lazy load modules not in `shared.module.ts`

Comment: Are you importing this component in any ionic page? if yes, import ReactiveFormsModule in that page.module.ts or import shared.module.ts inside that page.module.ts

Comment: Thanks everyone, problem solved, I posted a solution to the bottom of this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Update, problem solved :)

> app.module.ts

```js
...
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SharedModule } from './components/shared-module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

> shared-module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CoinViewComponent } from '../components/coin-view/coin-view.component';
import { SearchResultsSkeletonComponent } from './search-results-skeleton/search-results-skeleton.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [],
    exports: [...],
    schemas: [...]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

To sum it up
 - Add `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, SharedModule` to `imports[]` on `app.module.ts`.
 - Add `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` to `shared-module.ts`.
 - No need to add `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` on an ionic page.module.ts.

Comment: I have the same issue but I am not using a shared module... I have done all the imports and added them to the import array as well but the problem still persists. Would you be able to help?

Comment: We can certainly try. Is it ionic or pure angular? If you could describe your layout with code blocks as I did above, that would be helpful, please.

Comment: Hey thank you for the message! I have been working on this for 2 days and I wasn't able to get it to work in my ionic page that I was testing it on... I did get it to work in the app.component.ts, app.component.html and app.module.ts. The same code I copied and pasted but never worked...

Comment: ... I then did the same thing for another page and it did work (that page was in the same sub-directory as the one that didn't) and the only difference is that the page that didn't work had a number in its name (tab3 it was called) and the other one that work was named (register) without numbers so maybe it is the number in the name that messed up everything.

Comment: That’s very strange, I would doubt it’s a number but who knows, glad you got it working!

Comment: Thanks for the support :) I literally wanted to cry but thank God :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how application should be constructed:

app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    NavBarComponent,
    ProgressBarComponent,
    SocialMediaComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    TranslModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts and inside lazyLoadModules:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeModule } from './routes/home/home.module';
import { AboutModule } from './routes/about/about.module';
import { NewsModule } from './routes/news/news.module';
import { PricesModule } from './routes/prices/prices.module';
import { BookingModule } from './routes/booking/booking.module';
import { ContactModule } from './routes/contact/contact.module';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './components/not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './routes/home/home.module#HomeModule' },
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: './routes/about/about.module#AboutModule' },
  { path: 'news', loadChildren: './routes/news/news.module#NewsModule' },
  { path: 'prices', loadChildren: './routes/prices/prices.module#PricesModule' },
  { path: 'booking', loadChildren: './routes/booking/booking.module#BookingModule' },
  { path: 'contact', loadChildren: './routes/contact/contact.module#ContactModule' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav-bar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-nav-bar>
<app-social-media></app-social-media>
```

nav-bar.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'" [mode]="'over'" [opened]="false">
    <img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/mises543/logo-163x70-Hart_Ilona_Borys_t-1gtTLMj.png" alt="Ilona Borys logo."
      style="height: 45px; padding-top: 5px;">
    <div class='sidenav-links'>
      <a mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" [ngClass]="active ? 'active': ''"
        routerLink="/">{{'app.nav-buttons.home' | translate}}</a>
      <a mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLink="/about">{{'app.nav-buttons.about' | translate}}</a>
      <a mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLink="/news">{{'app.nav-buttons.news' | translate}}</a>
      <a mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLink="/prices">{{'app.nav-buttons.prices' | translate}}</a>
      <a mat-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" routerLinkActive="active"
        routerLink="/booking">{{'app.nav-buttons.booking' | translate}}</a>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <span><img src="https://ik.imagekit.io/mises543/logo-163x70-Hart_Ilona_Borys_t-1gtTLMj.png"
          alt="Ilona Borys logo." style="height: 45px; padding-top: 5px;"></span>
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <div class="navbar-mid-a">
        <a *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" mat-button [ngClass]="active ? 'active': ''"
          routerLink="/">{{'app.nav-buttons.home' | translate}}</a>
        <a *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" mat-button routerLinkActive="active"
          routerLink="/about">{{'app.nav-buttons.about' | translate}}</a>
        <a *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" mat-button routerLinkActive="active"
          routerLink="/news">{{'app.nav-buttons.news' | translate}}</a>
        <a *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" mat-button routerLinkActive="active"
          routerLink="/prices">{{'app.nav-buttons.prices' | translate}}</a>
        <a *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)" mat-button routerLinkActive="active"
          routerLink="/booking">{{'app.nav-buttons.booking' | translate}}</a>
      </div>
      <a mat-icon-button class="center" matTooltip='Contact uss.' routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/contact">
        <mat-icon aria-label="contact icon">mail_outline</mat-icon>
      </a>
      <a type="button" class="center" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon" color="black">menu</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- Content from router-outlet goes here. -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I show nav-bar.component.html becouse you might dont know, how  are shown in this component.

home.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    HomeRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home-routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

shared.module.ts is a place where you export modules you will use across many other modules:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FirebaseModule.forRoot(),
        MaterialModule,
        TranslateModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FirebaseModule,
        MaterialModule,
        TranslateModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        MetaService,
        SnackService,
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

In `MaterialModule` i have my all `Angular Material`.
In `FirebaseModule` i have my database connection modules.
In `TranslateModule` is from `ngx-translate` library it will be every where so i import and export it in shared module.
And in app module im importing `TranslModule` where i init `ngx-translate` library cose it can be init only in main module.

Comment: My application is constructed from a templated starter kit that ionic provides, which is slightly deviated from a typical angular app. Nevertheless, I have routing module, and my pages are lazy loaded, correct, just like shown on your example.

My problem is logistics of loading reactive forms. I haven't tried yet what I wanted to based on your answers earlier, I will try in a bit.

Basically I have:
```
page
|- componentX
page2
|- componentX
```

Comment: `componentX` is loaded via shared module. So I think maybe I should import reactive forms in that shared module.

Or import it via `app.module.ts`. I just noticed also that I am importing shared module in `app.module.ts` but I don't include it in `imports: [...]`, that's another problem to look at.

Comment: Oh i never used ionic library. ;]

Comment: Ya importing shared to `app.module.ts` could be and answer, but if you want to use it in other lazy loaded modules you need to import it to them to.